# SQL Server Connections Exhausted

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I do not know how to best diagnose or where to go regarding my issue, and would appreciate any help that could be offered.

This question addresses the **node-mssql** Node.JS library.

#### Primary Issue

I am running a Node.JS application based on a Socket.IO instance. Data is being pumped through to Socket.IO (the app), and then MSSQL is taking the received data and writing it to a database.

My issue is that scaling up the program to 300 concurrent Socket.IO connections, all feeding data, results in a bottleneck with database queries. This results in a non-descriptive timeout error:

```
Error: operation timed out for an unknown reason
    at C:\Users\jeanm\WebstormProjects\TikTokResearchNode\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:17:27
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

#### My Queries

Here are my queries that my project is making use of: https://pastebin.com/sr5AtNhS

There is one javascript-embedded query:
https://pastebin.com/w7gYeCQQ

Finally, there is a dynamic generator for queries. It's all the same type of query, but with different tables & fields:

```js
    static #build_query(table_name, keys = [], return_id = false) {

        return `
            INSERT INTO
                "${table_name}" (${keys.join(', ')})
            ${return_id ? 'OUTPUT INSERTED.id' : ''}
            VALUES
                (${"?".repeat(keys.length).split("").join(", ")}) 
        `
```

#### My Database

The following is my database design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ezN.jpg

#### What I've Tried

I read that increasing the connection pool is a valid strategy, and for me, with about 1500 queries per second if things worked the way they should, the pool having a max of 10 was obviously not enough.

This is my config:

```
{
        connectionString: 'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=localhost;Database=ResearchTest;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
        driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
        pool: {
            max: 16384,
            min: 256,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
    }
```

I just went for it, and gave it everything, to see if it was a matter of not enough connections. Well, surprise surprise, no, it's not.

#### What I've Debugged

Debugging what was happening showed me that the pool was steadily filling up to 5-10 "free"connections:

https://cdn.isaackogan.com/7zIjT

This would stay stable for about 30 seconds. Then, within 5 seconds of the last screenshot, it spiked:

https://cdn.isaackogan.com/y9peJ

What I believe this is telling me is that connections stopped being returned to the pool, so node-mssql tried to combat this by creating new connections, except those were also not being returned. And then, this just continued for a long time since the 'max' was 16384. Eventually, after 30 seconds, the timeout errors start being thrown.

#### What I Think The Cause Is

I do **not** have a lot of experience with MSSQL (in fact, the last few weeks are my first). In general, I am not very skilled with SQL, but my project requires it and I am not afraid of a learning curve.

My **observation** is that connections are not being returned to the pool, and this causes timeouts.
My **hypothesis** is that this would happen if a table is locked and hangs, though I am not sure.

An alternative hypothesis would be that really expensive queries cause a build-up that exhausts all connections.

#### My Questions

Essentially, I'm curious what people with more experience think. What are the potential reasons for what I've outlined is happening, and do you have any ideas what I can do to fix it? I know it is not an issue with the library, but my code, and I am willing to provide any information if you feel that you can help.

Is this a case of a table lock gone wrong? How would I diagnose and go about fixing that? If it's possible it's something else, what, and how can I find out?

I am also unsure how to debug something like this when there are thousands of queries interacting with the DB at a given time, how would I pin down the 1 where everything goes wrong to even KNOW what has gone wrong?

Any help/a direction to go in would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you making sure to dispose your connection objects as soon as the query is done?

Comment: It's handled by the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project is now running with 300 concurrent users/Socket.IO connections.

I made the following changes:

1. Setting `validateConnection: false` config option
2. Halve the number of 'requests' to the database by combining queries
3. Reduce the max pool to 50 (knowing how connections work now, it's funny I had it so large)

I am glad that I have 'extra' cards to pull if there is a scale issue in the future. These include (for my own self-reference):

1. Warming up the pool
2. Using Redis as temporary storage for batching
3. Sharding the storage script (1 data collection script -> n # of instances of the Node.JS storage script)

The bottleneck was absolutely sockets and not table locking.
For more info, see the issue that helped me: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1473